# Where is PHP.ini in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, php

I wanted to run some PHP right on my Mac, uncommented httpd.conf, activated web sharing, installed MySQL etc.
I can't seem to find my PHP files, most importantly, PHP.ini.

On my old machine it was located in /usr/local/php5/lib
But php5 directory doesn't exist in /usr/local..

Do I need to get a package or am I looking in the incorrect place?

Running OS X 10.7.3, PHP 5.3.8, Apache/2.2.21

Comment: Or `locate php.ini`

Comment: @ralfe It should be added that you need to look for the 'Loaded Configuration File' setting from phpinfo() or `php --ini` (run in terminal window). Because if there is no php.ini both of those will report the Configuration File Path as `/etc` (at least on my OS X 10.8 install). If no configuration file is loaded, then you should try the [answer by mac](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9343210/695671)

Comment: /usr/local/php5 is where the php-installer of entropy.ch and liip.ch install(ed) php. It has never been the location of Apples php-installation.

Comment: Do this `php -i | grep php.ini`

Comment: on Terminal enter php -r "phpinfo();"

Answer (score 413, accepted):

You should find it in /private/etc if it exists, otherwise:

```
sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
```

Comment: Okay, there's a php.ini.default in /private/etc and I'm checking it out. but any idea why don't I have my old php5 folder in usr/local? There used to be a bunch of files in there including a recommended php.ini. Is this a change in a newer version or PHP5 or Lion or something else?

Comment: PHP5 is included by default in MacOS X since 10.5 with the above location for the php.ini file. If you had installed it manually it should not have been removed during the upgrade to Lion; strange...

Comment: That was on an old machine from quite some time ago (tiger days). This machine is a fresh install. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The php.ini.default file on my Lion machine did not match all the default settings when no php.ini was present.  Notably short_tags was Off, error_reporting, log_errors, and some minor settings differed.  You will want to compare your output of `php -i` before and after creating your php.ini.

Comment: on my mac, I had a file at the /private/etc/php.ini  but php seemed to ignore any changes I made there, found it was using the one in /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini instead

Comment: this answer is bad since the location of the php.ini can varies depending on how PHP is installed, OS X version and how the user customises his installation

Comment: This answer pointed me to the right direction. cp php.ini.default > php.ini and CLI  loaded configuration became /etc/php.ini. Check php -i | grep php.ini after

Answer (score 549):

To locate the ini file on your machine, open `Terminal.app` and run the following command:

```
php --ini
```

---

If you need a template for Lion, try [this](https://gist.github.com/rkmax/5627754).

Comment: I have no loaded php.ini right now. Basically I'm looking for the directory with the "recommended" php.ini template.

Answer (score 56):

In terminal do `php -i | grep php.ini`.
Should give you some clues ;)

Answer (score 29):

Answers from @Cronk and @Justin got me close on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks.  In fact, on my system the `/etc/php.ini` file was missing completely, and it wasn't until I ran `phpinfo()` on the web server that I observed there was no configuration file.  Copying the file from `/etc/php.ini.default` and adding the *fully qualified path* to the `mcrypt.so` library to the config file solved the problem:

```
cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Then in `/etc/php.ini` add the following line (using the correct path to your `mcrypt.so` file):

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.29/mcrypt.so"
```

Then restart Apache2:

```
apachectl restart
```

Comment: omg, you are my hero!! thank you for the idea of using the full path of mcrypt!

Answer (score 28):

As pointed out, the `php --ini` command will tell you where PHP is expecting to find the php.ini file.

For a standard installation, it's likely to be looking for `/etc/php.ini`

If you've used *[macports](http://www.macports.org/)* then PHP may be looking for `/opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini`

Comment: etc is a link to private/etc: /etc -> private/etc

Answer (score 25):

Run `phpinfo()` from any file and it tells you where it is. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: this is the best way to go, as you might find copies of the php.ini in other "default" folders but this way will tell you the one it's actually using, so that way you avoid the head scratching and frustration that comes when you make a change but php seems to be totally unaware of said change.

Comment: You can also open up the php REPL in your shell by running `php -a` where you then run `phpinfo();`.

Answer (score 16):

I have more than once instance of PHP running so the other answers did not work for me. This did:

Create a PHP file and open its local url in your browser:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The PHP.INI path will be listed close to the top.

Answer (score 10):

1- Find `.ini` location path

Open Terminal and run command

```
php --ini
```

2- copy this path  `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`
and open it by command

```
nano /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

3-  Make changes and Quit with the keyboard combination Ctrl+X to exit nano

4- run  `apachectl restart` after finish

Comment: this solution works for mac users, because found the pho.ini file is dificult, so whit this solutions i can edit php.ini in my terminal. LIKE 

Answer (score 3):

This is rather old thread, but I would like to add a further clarification.

If you have a system that has multiple PHP installations (like mine did) the results you get from using the command line tools MAY BE different than what is actually used by the web server.  If you are interested in what PHP is being used by the web server, only use the information gathered from a web page that uses the 'phpinfo()' function.

For example, on my system the versions reported by the two different methods were:

> Command line:  5.3.26
>
> Web:   5.3.13

For the php.ini file path things were different, too:

> Command line:  /private/etc/php.ini
>
> Web: /long/path/to/the/file/php.ini

You can find all the possible php.ini files using this:

> find / -name php.ini 2>&1 | grep -v "denied" | grep -v "directory"

(the '2>&1' and 'grep' elements just restrict the output of the command to useful information, i.e. get rid of error messages)

On my system I found 3 INI files.  Because I was interested in what the web server was using I knew that I should use the path returned from the web-page results.  I made my changes to the php.ini file that was listed there, restarted apache, and re-ran the web page; the new edits were shown there.

To restart apache:

> sudo apachectl -k restart

--  J

Answer (score 3):

On OSX/MacOS do the following in a Terminal window:

Run `php --ini` at the prompt by typing it and pressing enter

Reports something like:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

...this is because in /etc there is a file called /etc/php.ini.default as an example and to show it is not in use.  You need to copy that file to the name php expects so that you can edit it, like this:

Type:

```
$  sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini       (and enter your password)
```

...then you will see if you run `php --ini` again that it now sees your new file:

Typing this: `php --ini` at the prompt should report this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

...now edit /etc/php.ini - you want to make sure the following lines (NOT the same line starting with a semi-colon ';') are exactly as follows:
`log_errors = On`     (this will turn the logging engine on)

Then, in this section:

```
; Log errors to specified file. PHP's default behavior is to leave this value
; empty.
; http://php.net/error-log
; Example:
;error_log = php_errors.log
; Log errors to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;error_log = syslog
```

If you want to log to the syslog (or Windows Event Log on Windows) then `;error_log = syslog` should become `error_log = syslog`

However, if as you say, you want to log to a file, you uncomment by removing the leading semi colon to make `;error_log = php_errors.log` become `error_log = php_errors.log` or using a full path to place it where you want.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I start with the 'Hello World!', once I get that displaying in my browser I throw a `phpinfo();` in there and you can see all of the things. Tells you which configurations are loaded, everything.

```
<?php
   echo 'Hello World!';

   phpinfo();
```

Answer (score -1):

You run php_info() and see line bellow :)

```
Loaded Configuration File   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete method to modify correct `php.ini` in mac.

- Find out the ini location via `php --ini`, this will give something like below:

```
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
    Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
    Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
    Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

- Now open the `php.ini` via `sudo vi /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`
- Make your changes and exit it via `:wq`
- Run final command `sudo apachectl restart`

You are changes should be now reflected, if done correctly :)