# PHP 5.4 extensions

Tags: php, macos, openssl

I am trying to confirm if I have mysql extension and mod_mcrypt, mod_mbstring as well as openssl installed on my recently installed version of MAMP. I have taken a look under phpmyinfo and see configure command section. For example './configure' '--with-mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library' Is it just a matter of entering this into terminal or is there anything else I need to do..

Comment: Scroll down the long list of installed extensions below the configure command.

Comment: One way to check PHP runtime configuration is to write a small script with just the line `<? phpinfo(); ?>` and then look at the generated page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are simply command line options passed to the C compiler when building PHP. Most extensions do not define such options.

The simplest way is to just have a look at the rest of `phpinfo()`'s output (possibly using your browser's "Search" feature). Many extensions add their own table there. Additionally, some extensions (not all!) provide version info you can retrieve with [phpversion()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php), e.g.:

```
var_dump( phpversion('mysqli') );
// 0.1
```

But the most generalizable and IMHO reliable method is just testing whether the features provided by the extension are available for you. You can use [function_exists()](http://php.net/function_exists) and [class_exists()](http://php.net/class_exists):

```
echo 'Mcrypt: ' . (function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt') ? 'Available' : 'Not available');
```

Comment: for mbstring I have multibyte support - enabled. But HTTP input encoding translation - disabled. Does this mean mstring is enabled or disabled? Thanks

Comment: @NATHANC PHP does not load disabled extensions. If it shows up in phpinfo(), it's there. But you don't have enabled the [HTTP input encoding translation](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php) feature. Enable it if you need it.

Comment: how do I go about enabling HTTP input encoding translation?

Comment: @NATHANC - Not clear what your question is. Do you know how to change PHP directives?

Comment: I just want to know how to enable the HTTP feature like you mentioned, if it is already disabled. Not sure if I will need it but for now I would like to. I am not sure how to change PHP directives.

Comment: @NATHANC - See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343151/where-is-php-ini-in-mac-os-x-lion-thought-it-was-in-usr-local-php5-lib).

Answer (score 1):

If you create a php page with just the following in it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And then view the output you can see if the various modules are enabled. If mcrypt is enab;led you will see section for it and the same for mbstring.

The following is output from my installation (sorry about the loss of formatting)

mcrypt

mcrypt support  enabled

Version 2.5.7

Api No  20021217

Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes

Supported modes cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value

mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value

mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

Comment: For mbstring I get..

Multibyte Support  enabled
Multibyte string engine  libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation  disabled
libmbfl version  1.3.2

Does this mean it is enabled? Thanks