# I can't find php.ini file on Mac?

Tags: php

I need to set `upload_tmp_dir` directive on my PHP server. I've read that there is a php.ini file which I can specify. But I can't find any php.ini files on my Mac. I'm using OSX 10.8. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343151/where-is-php-ini-in-mac-os-x-lion-thought-it-was-in-usr-local-php5-lib

Comment: I posted an answer. Hope that would be helpful. Any question please feel free to comment here. Good luck.

Comment: @halfer, thank you. I knew that :). I posted last comment because there were some comments not kindly on this question, though were deleted later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make php file with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

run in the browser, then you see the path of PHP configuration files ;)

Comment: i know about phpinfo. there is no way to change values in this page.

Comment: But there is path for php.ini

Comment: This doesn't work for me b/c I use MAMP so the browser uses the PHP executable provided by MAMP and the Mac Terminal uses the one provided by the OS.

Answer (score 55):

Run the command below on your server:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

then you can see something like below:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php54/php.ini
```

Comment: This is the best answer and should be the chosen one.

Comment: @Aaron  Thanks. :), Have a good day.

Comment: This is the CLI one..I am search the ini which is used by Apache how to find it. In phpinfo it say /etc and there is not php.ini in /etc

Answer (score 4):

if you use the mac os default install php ,the php.ini at /etc/php.ini