# Change enclosing PHP script tags

Tags: php, macos

I run PHP 5.4.24 on Mac OS X. Looks like

```
<?php
```

is accepted as PHP tag enclosing scripts but not

```
<?
```

How can this be changed? It would be nice if both would work.

Comment: `<?php` is *the* correct PHP opening tag. `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php echo`. That is all.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - What are you talking about?

Comment: @j08691 I mean that `<?` is discouraged. One reason being `<?xml` headers cause it to get confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activate the short open tags **(short_open_tag)** in your **php.ini**

The default file is under `/private/etc/php.ini`

Perhaps this could help:

[Where is PHP.ini in Mac OS X Lion? Thought it was in /usr/local/php5/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343151/where-is-php-ini-in-mac-os-x-lion-thought-it-was-in-usr-local-php5-lib)

Answer (score 3):

Set `short_open_tag` in php.ini to true

Answer (score 3):

The configuration setting is called `short_open_tag`. You change it in your php.ini.