# OSX Sierra - how to increase PHP memory limit correctly?

Tags: php, macos, macos-sierra

I need to increase the memory limit for PHP on the command line so I can use Composer.

Output of `php -i | grep memory_limit`

> memory_limit => 256M => 256M

Output of `php --ini`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php5/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/20-extension-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/40-openssl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-apcu.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-curl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-gmp.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-imap.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-intl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-memcache.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mongo.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mssql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-oauth.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pdo_dblib.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-propro.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-raphf.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-readline.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-redis.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-solr.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-ssh2.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-twig.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-uploadprogress.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xhprof.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xsl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/60-extension-pecl_http.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini
```

So I edit `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini` but it's always 256MB...

Restarted Apache, but it's cli, but still no success.

Comment: Make sure you edit the correct `php.ini`

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343151/where-is-php-ini-in-mac-os-x-lion-thought-it-was-in-usr-local-php5-lib). It's for Lion, but I think it still applies for Sierra

Comment: Thanks, but in my case it seems to be outdated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the other included files has a `memory_limit` directive. Use this command to find which one:

```
grep memory_limit /usr/local/php5/php.d/*
```

The "Additional .ini files parsed" are parsed later, and will override settings in the main `php.ini`.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you should find out where php.ini is

sometimes this won't do:

```
php -i | grep php.ini   # turns out I just can't edit /etc/php.ini even when I'm root
```

then you can try this:

```
locate php.ini  # turns out it's here: /private/etc/php.ini
```

finally, edit /private/etc/php.ini with sudo

```
sudo vim /private/etc/php.ini
```

save the file with

```
:wq!
```

job done.

Comment: saving with :wq!, translates to quit without saving => !  discards the changes

Comment: @Gunnrryy  :wq! just means force write and quit in one command. If the file was modified and you wanted to quit without saving, you would use :q!.

Comment: In what cases will `php -i` not give you accurate information about which ini files are being applied? I’m not sure macOS comes with `vim`, but if you feel the need to give instructions on how to quit `vi` then why not how to enter insert/append mode? The directive could be in any of multiple files not named `php.ini`, as in the OP’s case, where they already edited that file to no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that you need to change the memory limit in this file :

`/usr/local/etc/php/*your php version*/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`

Worked like a charm after modifying this file.